# Stored procedure get a list of the parameters that contain values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a stored procedure with 10 optional parameters, like this:

```
usp_MySP
    @Name varchar(50)
    @Height varChar(3)
    @Weight int
    @Haircolor varchar(10)
    @Eyecolor varchar(10)....
```

If the stored procedure is executed with `Weight` and `Haircolor` values, I want to assign a variable that contains the parameter names that are being used.

```
DECLARE @MyParams varchar(100)
```

Something like this:

```
SET @MyParams = NULLIF(@name, 'name') + ' , ' +
                NULLIF(@weight, 'Weight') + ' , ' + 
                ISNULL(@Haircolor, 'Haircolor')...
```

(Concat any NULL values = Null?)

Is this the best solution? Alternatives?

So if `Weight` and `Haircolor` are provided

```
@MyParam = 'Weight, Haircolor'
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest is probably `CONCAT_WS` which concatenates with a separator and ignores nulls. Combine that with `CASE`, which returns null in the absence of an `ELSE`.

```sql
SET @MyParams =
  CONCAT_WS(', ',
    CASE WHEN @name IS NOT NULL THEN 'name' END,
    CASE WHEN @weight IS NOT NULL THEN 'Weight' END,
    CASE WHEN @Haircolor IS NOT NULL THEN 'Haircolor' END
  );
```

Comment: Altrenate syntax might be `IIF( boolean_expression, true_value, false_value )` ex `IIF(@name IS NOT NULL,'name' ,NULL)`

Answer (score 1):

An alternative

```
 SELECT @MyParams = STRING_AGG(name, ',')
 FROM (VALUES 
    (NULL, CAST(NULL AS SQL_VARIANT)), /*Avoid issues with strings being cast to int*/
    ('Name', @Name),
    ('Height', @Height),
    ('Weight', @Weight),
    ('Haircolor', @Haircolor),
    ('Eyecolor', @Eyecolor)
    ) v(name, val)
 WHERE val IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Would that work with nvarchar(max) params?

Comment: @siggemannen - No you wouldn't be able to implicitly `CAST` those as SQL Variant so would not be able to use the parameter directly for those. Could use an expression like `CASE WHEN @Haircolor IS NOT NULL THEN '' END`  for those.